# Get all Job id's for a Hive Query using post hook

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to get application id of all MapReduce jobs for a Hive query? I can look into history or timeline server and get Hive Query strings for every application id. But, was wondering whether I can get userid, all application id from Hive's post hook?

Comment: Was there a solution this? thank you